# Can I earn achievements in Civilisation 6 with changed settings?

Tags: achievements, civilization-6

Can I get an achievement if I'm playing the game with a few settings changes, like 'quick' speed instead of 'normal', or with 'no tribal villages'/'no barbarians' on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, you sure can.

The only thing that prevents you from getting achievements is running with non-DLC mods. I've already gotten a few despite disabling the unit cycling and decreasing the tooltip delay.